# I Can't deploy my product to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

My code use to work but now when i try to deploy my code to heroku i got this.

> git push heroku master

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 463 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Warning:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at
 all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.1)
       Using i18n (0.6.1)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using multi_json (1.8.4)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using arel (3.0.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using addressable (2.3.5)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using mini_portile (0.5.2)
       Using uuidtools (2.1.4)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Using daemons (1.1.9)
       Using eventmachine (1.0.3)
       Using orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Using netrc (0.7.7)
       Using rubyzip (1.1.0)
       Using excon (0.31.0)
       Using moped (1.5.2)
       Using origin (1.1.0)
       Using sass (3.2.14)
       Using will_paginate (3.0.5)
       Using activesupport (3.2.13)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using warden (1.2.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using rest-client (1.6.7)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using launchy (2.4.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using nokogiri (1.6.1)
       Using uglifier (2.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thin (1.6.1)
       Using heroku-api (0.3.17)
       Using activemodel (3.2.13)
       Using climate_control (0.0.3)
       Using jeapie (0.2.0)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using aws-sdk (1.34.0)
       Using heroku (3.3.0)
       Using actionpack (3.2.13)
       Using activerecord (3.2.13)
       Using activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using mongoid (3.1.6)
       Using cocaine (0.5.3)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Using railties (3.2.13)
       Using kaminari (0.15.1)
       Using paperclip (4.1.0)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using devise (3.2.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Using rails (3.2.13)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Using mongoid-paperclip (0.0.8)
       Installing diff-lcs (1.2.5)
       Installing rspec-mocks (2.14.5)
       Installing rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
       Installing rspec-core (2.14.7)
       Installing rspec (2.14.1)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (9.69s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       Could not detect rake tasks
       ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no envir
onment variables present
       and using the production group of your Gemfile.
       This may be intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run
       cancel the build (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:
       rake aborted!
       cannot load such file -- spec
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/config/application.rb:13:
in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/Rakefile:5:in `require'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/Rakefile:5:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
       /tmp/build_b7570745-8f64-47db-a14d-8cf677fd8f05/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
-----> WARNINGS:
       Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
       Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
       Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more inform
ation.

       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at
 all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 39.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       http://mysterious-stream-2588.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:mysterious-stream-2588.git
   e0094f9..38e08b5  master -> master
```

i don't know what to do  i've try  for long time.

i used ruby 1.9.3 & rails 3.2.13

This is my logs

> heroku logs

```
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <modul
e:Finisher>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_
or_load'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <m
ain>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config
'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.250597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializ
ers'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251403+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251403+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T10:32:34.251403+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2014-02-11T10:32:35.455560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-11T10:32:35.469448+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-02-11T11:03:06.303472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-02-11T11:03:10.671083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 13022`
2014-02-11T11:03:14.057237+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2014-02-11T11:03:14.057237+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
paperclip-4.1.0/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:89:in `add_active_record_call
backs': undef
ined method `after_commit' for Assign:Class (NoMethodError)
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/paperclip-4.1.0/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:19:in `define'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/paperclip-4.1.0/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:4:in `define_on'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/paperclip-4.1.0/lib/paperclip.rb:180:in `has_attached_file'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/mongoid-paperclip-0.0.8/lib/mongoid_paperclip.rb:70:in `has_mongoid_atta
ched_file'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/assign.rb:1
0:in `<class:Assign>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/assign.rb:1
:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
 require'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_
or_load'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_o
n'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_
dependency'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_lo
ad!'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <modul
e:Finisher>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializ
ers'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <m
ain>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dep
endency'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config
'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.283811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

2014-02-11T11:03:15.283991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2014-02-11T11:03:15.284568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
2014-02-11T11:03:16.619263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-11T11:15:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-02-11T11:15:41.523003+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 38e08b5 by mewkung.v@gmail.
com
2014-02-11T11:15:41.543899+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by mewkung.v@gm
ail.com
2014-02-11T11:15:41+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-02-11T11:15:45.996795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 43527`
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- s
pec (LoadError)
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
2:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <m
ain>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'

2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
2:in `require'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.838851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:
13:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:72:in `start'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839071+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config
'
2014-02-11T11:15:47.839228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2014-02-11T11:15:49.061476+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-11T11:15:49.078364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-02-11T11:15:49.079503+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
```

can anyone help me figure out.

Comment: Do you have `spec` directory checked into git repository?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You have an invalid statement in your Rakefile or Gemfile. You probably meant 'rspec' or 'rspec-rails' instead. Rake itself is telling you so:

cannot load such file -- spec

Solution

Remove the reference to "spec" in your Rakefile or Gemfile, or replace the problematic line with the correct name of the gem or library you're trying to use.